# Decision table with large number of conditions and actions

Tags: rule-engine

If the number of conditions and actions is high (in my case, 12 conditions and 13 actions respectively!), making/maintaining a decision table with hand is proving to be really tough. The number of possible rules in the case at hand is huge (Y/N for 11 conditions and a 3-way choice for the 12th) and it's freaking me out. Also, these conditions and actions cannot be collapsed/coalesced; they are all needed very much.

What could be a better alternative to a decision table? What are some popular free tools to model the same?

Thanks so much.

Comment: I've posted somewhat the same question with an example just now because I felt you where not getting the answers you should've gotten. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101879/how-to-start-working-with-a-large-decision-table

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [ROBDDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROBDD).

Comment: Thanks...can you pls. point me to a book that explains creation and reduction of BDDs in a simple way?

Comment: The wikipedia article links to some articles and books.

Comment: By the way, why would an ROBDD be suitable for my model in question? I am not really looking at a binary 0 or 1 answer....I am looking at 8-9 possible actions to be taken based on the combinations of values of 11-12 conditions .... correct me if I am wrong, but an ROBDD doesn't seem intuitive to me here.

Comment: You can encode a condition for each action and test them efficiently with ROBDDs.

Comment: OK - you mean, let the terminal nodes of 0 & 1 stand for "Don't do this action" and "Do this action", and the ordered variables be the conditions that lead up to these 0/1? (Of course, this would lead to 1 ROBDD per action...) - please let me know if I'm right.

Answer (score 0):

[Statestep](http://statestep.com/) might be what you're looking for. Really powerful for dealing with large numbers of possibilities. Not normally free though, unless for education etc.