# How to start working with a large decision table

Tags: rule-engine

Today I've been presented with a fun challenge and I want your input on how you would deal with this situation.

So the problem is the following (I've converted it to demo data as the real problem wouldn't make much sense without knowing the company dictionary by heart).

We have a decision table that has a minimum of 16 conditions. Because it is an impossible feat to manage all of them (2^16 possibilities) we've decided to only list the exceptions. Like this:

[image: decision table example]

As an example I've only added 10 conditions but in reality there are (for now) 16. The basic idea is that we have one baseline (the default) which is valid for everyone and all the exceptions to this default.

**Example:**

You have a foreigner who is also a pirate. 
If you go through all the exceptions one by one, and condition by condition you remove the exceptions that have at least one condition that fails. In the end you'll end up with the following two exceptions that are valid for our case. The match is on the IsPirate and the IsForeigner condition. But as you can see there are 2 results here, well 3 actually if you count the default.
[image: problem example]

**Our solution**

Now what we came up with on how to solve this is that in the GUI where you are adding these exceptions, there should run an algorithm which checks for such cases and force you to define the exception more specifically. This is only still a theory and hasn't been tested out but we think it could work this way.

**My Question**

I'm looking for alternative solutions that make the rules manageable and prevent the problem I've shown in the example.

Comment: Yarr, I don't understand yer question.  What be the input?  Is it the last line "1110100000"?  What be the desired output?  Please update yer question with more detail, matey.

Comment: Hey, I've updated the question a bit, dunno if I can make it clearer though. And yes the input is the foreign pirate example being 1110100000. Thanks for reading matey :) have some rum!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem seem to be resolution of conflicting rules.  When multiple rules match your input, (your foreigner and pirate) and they end up recommending different things (your cangetjob and cangetevicted), you need a strategy for *resolution* of this conflict.

What you mentioned is one way of resolution -- which is to remove the conflict in the first place.  However, this may not always be possible, and not always desirable because when a user adds a new rule that conflicts with a set of old rules (which he/she did not write), the user may not know how to revise it to remove the conflict.

Another possible resolution method is *prioritization*.  Mark a priority on each rule (based on things like the user's own authority etc.), sort the matching rules according to priority, and apply in ascending sequence of priority.  This usually works and is much simpler to manage (e.g. everybody knows that the top boss's rules are final!)

Prioritization may also be used to mark a certain rule as "global override".  In your example, you may want to make "IsPirate" as an override rule -- which means that it overrides settings for normal people.  In other words, once you're a pirate, you're treated differently.  This make it very easy to design a system in which you have a bunch of normal business rules governing 90% of the cases, then a set of "exceptions" that are treated differently, automatically overriding certain things.  In this case, you should also consider making "?" available in the output columns as well.

One other possible resolution method is to include attributes in each of your conditions. For example, certain conditions must have no "zeros" in order to pass (? doesn't matter).  Some conditions must have at least one "one" in order to pass.  In other words, mark each condition as either "AND", "OR", or "XOR".  Some popular file-system security uses this model.  For example, CanGetJob may be AND (you want to be stringent on rights-to-work).  CanBeEvicted may be OR -- you may want to evict even a foreigner if he is also a pirate.

An enhancement on the AND/OR method is to provide a threshold that the total result must exceed before passing that condition.  For example, putting CanGetJob at a threshold of 2 then it must get at least two 1's in order to return 1.  This is sometimes useful on conditions that are not clearly black-and-white.

You can mix resolution methods: e.g. first prioritize, then use AND/OR to resolve rules with similar priorities.

The possibilities are limitless and really depends on what your actual needs are.

Comment: Wow you've given some really good feedback here, thank you very much for taking the time to do so! Have a +50 ;-)

Comment: Well thanks.  :-)  However, I believe you still have some time left for the bounty, and you probably should have waited until the last minute before awarding.  Somebody else may come up with an even better answer for you.  But thanks anyway.

Comment: Still a good idea in your UI to highlight any potential conflicts so that the user knows that his/her rule may be overridden due to conflict resolution!

Comment: @Peter, I've edited my answer to include some more ideas on prioritization.

Comment: Yeah but your answer contained what I was looking for so I happily grant you the 50 rep :-) Thanks for the additional information!

Answer (score 3):

To me this problem reminds [business rules engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_rules_engine) where there is no known algorithm to define outputs from inputs (e.g. using boolean logic) but the user (typically some sort of administrator) has to define all or some the logic itself.

This might sound a bit of an overkill but OTOH this provides virtually limit-less extension capabilities: you don't have to code any new business logic, just define a new rule set.

As I understand your problem, you are looking for a nice way to visualise the editing for these rules. But this all depends on your programming language and the tool you select for this. Java, for example, has [JBoss Drools](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-flow.html). Quoting their page:

> Drools Guvnor provides a (logically
>   centralized) repository to store you
>   business knowledge, and a web-based
>   environment that allows business users
>   to view and (within certain
>   constraints) possibly update the
>   business logic directly.

You could possibly use this generic tool or write your own.

Answer (score 1):

Everything depends on what your actual rules will look like.  Rules like **'IF has an even number of these properties THEN'** would be painful to represent in this format, whereas rules like **'IF pirate and not geek THEN'** are easy.

You can 'avoid the ambiguity' by stating that you'll always be taking the *first* actual match, in other words your rules have a priority.  You'd then want to flag rules which have no effect because they are 'shadowed' by rules higher up.  They're not hard to find, so it's something your program should do.

Your interface could also indicate groups of rules where rules within the group can be in any order without changing the outcomes.  This will add clarity to what the rules are really saying.

If some of your outputs are relatively independent of the others, you will also get a more compact and much clearer table by allowing **question marks in the output**.  In that design the scan for first matching rule is done once for each output.  Consider for example if 'HasChildren' is the only factor relevant to 'Can Be Evicted'. With question marks in the outputs (= no effect) you could be halving the number of exception rules.

My background for this is circuit logic design, not business logic.  What you're designing is similar to, but not the same as, a [PLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_Logic_Array).  As long as your actual rules are close to sum of products then it can work well.  If your rules aren't, for example the 'even number of these properties' rule, then the grid like presentation will break down in a combinatorial explosion of cases.  Your best hope **if your rules are arbitrary** is to get a clearer more compact presentation with either equations or with diagrams like a circuit diagram.  To be avoided, if you can.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a Decision Engine with a GUI, than you can try this one: http://gandalf.nebo15.com/

We just released it, it's open source and production ready.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need some kind of inference engine. Think about doing it in prolog.